# Show that $(-1)^{n}\left( (n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}-n^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)=\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n} \right) $

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I would like to show:

$$(-1)^{n}\left( (n+1)^{\dfrac{1}{n+1}}-n^{\dfrac{1}{n}}\right)=\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n} \right) $$

Here is my attempt

\begin{align*}
(-1)^{n}\left( (n+1)^{\dfrac{1}{n+1}}-n^{\dfrac{1}{n}}\right)&=(-1)^{n}\left( \exp\left[\dfrac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1} \right]-\exp\left[\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n} \right]\right)  \\
&=(-1)^{n}\left( 1+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1} \right)-1-\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n} \right)\right) \\
&=(-1)^{n}\left( \mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1} \right)+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n} \right)\right) \\
&=(-1)^{n}\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n} \right)
\end{align*}

I can't prove that :
$$\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1} \right)+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n} \right)=\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n} \right) $$

- Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**

$1$. First note that

$$\dfrac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1} = O\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n} \right)$$

$2$. Also you should know that

$$O(O(f(n)))=O(f(n))$$

$3$. At last

$$O(f(n))+O(f(n))=O(f(n))$$

---

To prove $(1)$, you should just compute the following limit

$$\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln [n+1]}{n+1} \frac{n}{\ln n} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+1} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln[n+1]}{\ln n} \\
&=1 \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln[n+1]}{\ln n} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln[n+1]}{\ln n} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{n+1}}{\frac{1}{n}} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+1} \\
&= 1
\end{align}$$

where I used the **L'Hoptial** rule.

Comment: i already know that my problem i can't prove $\dfrac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1} = O\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n} \right)$

Comment: $$\left| \dfrac{\dfrac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1} }{\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n} } \right| = \dfrac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)}\times \dfrac{n}{n+1} \leq$$

Comment: @Educ: See the updated answer. :)

Comment: which means also $ \dfrac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1} \sim \dfrac{\ln(n)}{n} $

Comment: @Educ:Yeah. :) That's it

Comment: @Educ: Did my answer help you? :)

Comment: yeah thank you  i already +1

Comment: @Educ: Do you want me to add the whole details for accepting the answer? :)